# Combine two vectors into single list

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of variables with two sets of identifying numbers. I just used paste to get the vectors, so I have :

```
in <- "abc001":"abc050"
```

and

```
out <- "001xyz":"200xyz"
```

I want to combine them so that every value is accounted for. I tried `paste(in, "-", out, separate="")` which gives:

"abc001-001xyz"

But only until I hit 200xyz. How can I get a list of every possible combination of those values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You obviously haven't run that code.

Comment: I apologize. I'm very new and it was an example I came up with off the top of my head while typing on my phone. I will read more about proper etiquette for questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `expand.grid`:

```
df <- expand.grid(in, out)
paste(df$in,df$out, separate = "-")
```

Comment: Try using `in` as a variable name.

Comment: I know. I'm not going to put in more effort than OP

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the poor etiquette. I'm very new to programming in any way and just typed the example off the top of my head from my phone. I'll put in more effort in the future. Thank you again for the help.